# How to filter the tree view with the filtered ids?

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I created a wizard with two fields `od_document_type`, `od_employee` and then I filtered one custom model using these fields. I'm getting the filtered `id`s in the `document_datas`. Now I want to return the custom model's tree view with these filtered `ids`.

> Code

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from odoo import api, fields, models, _

class OrchidPassportTracking(models.TransientModel):
    _name = "orchid.passport.tracking"

    od_document_type = fields.Many2one('orchid.document.type',string="Document Type")
    od_employee = fields.Many2one('hr.employee',string="Employee")

    def find_status(self):
        domain = []
        if self.od_document_type:
            document_type_domain = ('doc_id','=',self.od_document_type.id)
            domain.append(document_type_domain)
        if self.od_employee:
            employee_domain = ('employee_id','=',self.od_employee.id)
            domain.append(employee_domain)
        document_datas = self.env['orchid.document.expiry'].search(domain)

        return {
            'name':'Passport Tracking',
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'tree,form',
            'res_model': 'orchid.document.expiry',
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'action':'action_orchid_document_type',
            'domain':{'id':[('id','in',document_datas.id)]},
        }
```

I tried like this but the tree view is showing the whole contents instead of the filtered contents.What to do ? 
Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Try thi this code: 'domain':{'id':[('id','in',document_datas.ids)]}

Comment: @KbiR Still showing the whole record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code,

```py
return {
        'name':'Passport Tracking',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'tree,form',
        'res_model': 'orchid.document.expiry',
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'action':'action_orchid_document_type',
        'domain':[('id','in',document_datas.ids)],
    }
```

Comment: It works... Thanks Man.. 
Can you please tell me the working.. I haven't seen `ids` before.

Comment: If you use `.ids`, then system will create a list of ids.

Comment: Ok Man.. Thanks a lot.. @kbir